# Two pay cards and a Just Say No

Tags: monopoly-deal

If I play 2 rent cards and an opponent plays a just say no card, how many rents does it cancel? one rent or two?

Comment: What game are you asking about?

Comment: Probably Monopoly Deal

Answer (score 2):

"Just Say No" cancels the effect of a single card. So if you have two rent cards to play, you should play them one at at time to see if your opponent plays JSN to each.